# How to pass multiple parameters in a querystring

Tags: asp.net, query-string

I have three values which I have to pass as parameters for e.g., `strID`, `strName` and `strDate`.

I want to redirect these three parameters to another page in `Response.Redirect()`.Can anybody provide me with the correct querystring?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

[Query_string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Structure)

(Following is the text of the linked section of the Wikipedia entry.)

### Structure

A typical URL containing a query string is as follows:

`http://server/path/program?query_string`

When a server receives a request for such a page, it runs a program (if configured to do so), passing the query_string unchanged to the program. The question mark is used as a separator and is not part of the query string.

A link in a web page may have a URL that contains a query string, however, HTML defines three ways a web browser can generate the query string:

- a web form via the ... element
- a server-side image map via the ​ismap​ attribute on the  element with a  construction
- an indexed search via the now deprecated  element

#### Web forms

The main use of query strings is to contain the content of an HTML form, also known as web form. In particular, when a form containing the fields field1, field2, field3 is submitted, the content of the fields is encoded as a query string as follows:

`field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3...`

- The query string is composed of a series of field-value pairs.
- Within each pair, the field name and value are separated by an equals sign. The equals sign may be omitted if the value is an empty string.
- The series of pairs is separated by the ampersand, '&' (or semicolon, ';' for URLs embedded in HTML and not generated by a ...; see below).
  While there is no definitive standard, most web frameworks allow multiple values to be associated with a single field:

`field1=value1&field1=value2&field1=value3...`

For each field of the form, the query string contains a pair field=value. Web forms may include fields that are not visible to the user; these fields are included in the query string when the form is submitted

This convention is a W3C recommendation. W3C recommends that all web servers support semicolon separators in addition to ampersand separators[6] to allow application/x-www-form-urlencoded query strings in URLs within HTML documents without having to entity escape ampersands.

Technically, the form content is only encoded as a query string when the form submission method is GET. The same encoding is used by default when the submission method is POST, but the result is not sent as a query string, that is, is not added to the action URL of the form. Rather, the string is sent as the body of the HTTP request.

Answer (score 39):

```
Query String: ?strID=XXXX&strName=yyyy&strDate=zzzzz
```

before you redirect:

```
string queryString = Request.QueryString.ToString();

Response.Redirect("page.aspx?"+queryString);
```

Answer (score 16):

Try like this.It should work

```
Response.Redirect(String.Format("yourpage.aspx?strId={0}&strName={1}&strDate{2}", Server.UrlEncode(strId), Server.UrlEncode(strName),Server.UrlEncode(strDate)));
```

Answer (score 10):

```
~mypage.aspx?strID=x&strName=y&strDate=z
```

Answer (score 10):

This can be done by using:

```
Response.Redirect("http://localhost/YourControllerName/ActionMethodName?querystring1=querystringvalue1&querystring2=querystringvalue2&querystring3=querystringvalue3");
```

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar this "link" is a url pointing to localhost and is part of the answer. Please don't "robo-review."

Answer (score 2):

Multiple query parameters Example:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/mycontroller/myaction?querystring1=querystringvalue1&querystring2=querystringvalue2&querystring3=querystringvalue3
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the AbsoluteUri and you can get it like this:

```
string myURI = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
 if (!WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated) {
        Response.Redirect("~/Login?returnUrl="
            + Request.Url.AbsoluteUri );
```

Then after you login:

```
var returnUrl = Request.QueryString["returnUrl"];
 if(WebSecurity.Login(username,password,true)){
                Context.RedirectLocal(returnUrl);
```

It works well for me.