# translate a PHP $string using google translator API

Tags: php, google-translate

been google'ing for a while how is the best way to translate with google translator in PHP, found very different ways converting URLS, or using Js but i want to do it only with php (or with a very simple solution JS/JQUery)

example:

```
//hopefully with $from_lan and $to_lan being like 'en','de', .. or similar
function translate($from_lan, $to_lan, $text){

// do

return $translated_text;

}
```

can you give me a clue? or maybe you already have this function..

my intention it's to use it only for the languages i have not already defined (or keys i haven't defined), that's why i wan it so simple, will be only temporal..

EDIT

thanks for your replies we are now trying this soulutions:

```
function auto_translate($from_lan, $to_lan, $text){
// do


$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?v=1.0&q=' . urlencode($text) . '&langpair=' . $from_lan . '|' . $to_lan));
$translated_text = $json->responseData->translatedText;


return $translated_text;
```

}

(there was a extra 'g' on variables  for lang... anyway)

it returns: works now :)

i don't really understand much the function, so any idea why is not acepting the object? (now i do)

OR:

```
    function auto_translate($from_lan, $to_lan, $text){
    // do

//    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?v=1.0&q=' . urlencode($text) . '&langpair=' . $from_lan . '|' . $to_lan));
//    $translated_text = $json['responseData']['translatedText'];
    error_reporting(1);
    require_once('GTranslate.php');
    try{
       $gt = new Gtranslate();
       $translated_text = $gt->english_to_german($text);

     } catch (GTranslateException $ge)
     {
           $translated_text= $ge->getMessage();
     }


    return $translated_text;
}
```

And this one looks great but it doesn't even gives me an error, the page won't load (error_report(1) :S)

thanks in advance!

Comment: json_decode returns an object, not an array.  So, you'd have to do `$json->responseData->translatedText` rather than `$json['responseData']['translatedText']`, which I now see that you got below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I haven't tested this yet, but try:

```
function translate($from_lan, $to_lan, $text){
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?v=1.0&q=' . urlencode($text) . '&langpair=' . $from_lan . '|' . $to_lan));
    $translated_text = $json->responseData->translatedText;

    return $translated_text;
}
```

EDIT: Fixed, tested and works.

Comment: thank you very much! updated the question with your code (there was a litter error) and explaining the error :( but it we can make it work it's exactly what i need! and sure is usefull for many others

Comment: i get an error. Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in D:\translate.php on line 166
Warning: file_get_contents(https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?v=1.0&q=Translate&langpair=auto|es) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\translate.php on line 166
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\translate.php on line 167
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\translate.php on line 167

Comment: Unfortunately this no longer works.  Google is blocking all 3rd party requests

Comment: @AlBeebe any reference about that?

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html

error please use this when i try this script in php

Comment: This is answer is no longer valid

Answer (score 6):

I have new solution for this.. Because last solution need new version and some fetched  other issue.

---

```
    $text = 'Test new message only.';
    $apiKey = '<past your google api key here>';
    $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=' . $apiKey . '&q=' . rawurlencode($text) . '&source=en&target=fr';
    $handle = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($handle);
    $responseDecoded = json_decode($response, true);

    curl_close($handle);

    print_r($responseDecoded['data']['translations'][0]['translatedText']);
    die;

    //expected output
     Testez le nouveau message uniquement.
```

I hope is very helpful in PHP

Comment: the question asks about plain PHP , absolutely nothing implies the OP is using packages to implement `curl`

Answer (score 3):

Want to use Google Translate API in PHP, you would need to insert "google/cloud-translate" and "google/apiclient" in your composer file, run composer update and call translate method after creating an object of the following class:

```
<?php

require_once APP_ROOT . '/library/google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once APP_ROOT . '/library/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_TranslateService.php';

class GoogleTranslator
{
    private $developer_key;

    const PROVIDER = "google";
    const SUCCESS = "success";
    const FAILURE = "failure";
    const TRANSLATE_SUCCESS_MESSAGE = 'text translation successful';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->developer_key = '<DEVELOPER KEY HERE>';
    }

    public function translate($text, $source_language, $target_language)
    {
        try {
            $client = new \Google_Client();
            $client->setApplicationName('Google Translate PHP Starter Application');

            $client->setDeveloperKey($this->developer_key);
            $service = new \Google_TranslateService($client);

            $optional_parameters = array('source' => $source_language);

            $translated_text = $service->translations->listTranslations($text, $target_language, $optional_parameters);
            return array('translation' => $translated_text['translations'][0]['translatedText'],
                'provider' => self::PROVIDER,
                'status' => self::SUCCESS,
                'message' => self::TRANSLATE_SUCCESS_MESSAGE);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            error_log($e->getMessage() . " FOR GET TRANSLATION CALL", "GOOGLE TRANSLATE API");
            $res = array('translation' => '',
                'provider' => self::PROVIDER,
                'status' => self::FAILURE,
                'message' => $e->getMessage());
            return $res;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, but please note that you are giving an answer to a question - with an accepted answer - from 7 years ago

Answer (score 1):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<body>

<h1>My Web Page</h1>

<p>Hello everybody!</p>

<p>Translate this page:</p>


<div id="google_translate_element"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

<p>You can translate the content of this page by selecting a language in the select box.</p>

</body>
</html>


<?php 


 ?>
```

Comment: This is what I am exactly looking for straight and simple way. Thank you @Fahad Ali

Answer (score 0):

To get samples that work, view the README.md files that come with installation
(after running `composer require google/cloud-translate`).

This page comes up number one in search, so it was necessary to provide an update. Even [Google's own translating text (basic) PHP examples](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/translating-text) didn't work for me.

As of 2020, this returned quick results via web [browser query strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724526/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-in-a-querystring#724530). 
 Consider the [sanitizing user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/how-can-i-sanitize-user-input-with-php) if this is to be deployed as part of some front-facing application or website.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Translate\V2\TranslateClient;

$txt  = $_GET["q"];
$src  = $_GET["s"];
$targ = $_GET["t"];

$translate = new TranslateClient([
    'key' => 'Your API Key Here'
]);

// Translate text from english to french.
$result = $translate->translate($txt, [
    'source' => $src,
    'target' => $targ,
]);

echo $result['text'];
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a newly adaption from "Savetheinternet's" function.
It uses php_decode with flag true (JSON will returning associative arrays)

```
 <?php

    function translate($SourceLan, $TargetLan, $text)
    {
        $obj = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?q=' . urlencode($text) . '&source=' . $SourceLan . '&target=' . $TargetLan . '&format=text&key=YOUR_OWN_GOOGLE_API_KEY'), true);

        $TranslatedText = $obj['data']['translations']['0']['translatedText'];

        return $TranslatedText;
    }


    echo translate("de", "en", "Hallo Welt");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Translate any string using [Google translator API](https://code.google.com/apis/console)**

**Step 1:** Go to console

**Step 2:** Create a project and open it

**Step 3:** Search cloud translation in API library

[image: Search translation api]

**Step 4:** Click on Cloud Translation API from the displayed list.

[image: choose api]

**Step 5:** Enable API

[image: enable api]

**Step 6:** Create API Key from APIs & Services

[image: Create-credentials]

**Step 7:** Copy the generated API key:

[image: api-key]

---

Now, lets move to the PHP script for using Google Translate API

We are using [Translate-v2 API](https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2), which accepts following primary parameters:

- q: the input text
- source: the source language
- target: the target language

---

```
$inputText = 'Test input message';
$source = 'en'; //English
$target = 'es'; // Spanish
$encodedInputText = rawurlencode($inputText);
$googleApiKey = '<paste the google api key here>';

$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=$apiKey&q=$encodedInputText&source=$source&target=$target";

$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($handle);
$responseDecoded = json_decode($response, true);

curl_close($handle);

print_r($responseDecoded['data']['translations'][0]['translatedText']);
```

---

Alternatively, you can also do this using **Postman** and generate curl code:

[image: generate-curl-code-postman]

Comment: the question asks about plain PHP , absolutely nothing implies the OP is using packages to implement `curl`

Comment: @MwBakker Is there some issue with using `curl` in PHP?