# PHP read Japanese character, transform Japanese kanji into readable form

Tags: php, ruby-characters

I'm not sure if PHP is capable of this but,

I've got Japanese kanji characters 『漢字』being displayed. I'd like php (or some language) to read this character and display how to read it (either in katakana「かんじ」or romaji「kanji」)

This way I will be able to display characters like this.

```
kanji
かんじ
漢字
```

Basically, add furigana to kanji (how to read the character).

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. If you mean translate, I don't think PHP can directly do that, but you can find lot of translators which can work with PHP. check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640378/translate-a-php-string-using-google-translator-api

Comment: @bansi not quite translating. But getting the phonetic reading of the character. Does PHP have this capability?

Comment: I don't think PHP supports `phonetic reading`. This is not what you want but you can check [soundex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a trivial problem.

Consider the problems that will arise from verb conjugations (送りがな) as well as 音読み and 訓読み. How does PHP know the difference in reading between '食' in '食事' and '食べる'?

You need a morphological analyzer for this, such as `mecab`.

If you install `mecab` on your server, you can call it from php via `exec`.

```
$key='漢字';
$phonetic=exec( 'echo '.$key.' | mecab  -O yomi');
```

*note that yomi allows for phonetic reading to be displayed in katakana

To prevent encoding issues, you might want to run something like `putenv('LANG=en_US.UTF-8');` prior to the `exec` so that the `stdout` is not garbled when stored in a variable in php.

Even something like mecab cannot give you  100% accuracy due to the complex nature of Japanese sentences.