# How to pass multiple arguments while creating URL link (using Javascript)?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to pass multiple parameters on the same link.

I would like to pass the parameter 4 also on the link window.open("http://www.av.com"+parm5,") how do i write it.

Detail Expl.

I would like to pass value in the value prompts such as the output should look like (para4=12/23/2013 & para5= 12/29/2013)

//MicroStrategy/servlet/mstrWeb?Server=gm0&Project=gmai+Production+Enterprise&Port=0&evt=2048001&src=mstrWeb.2048001&documentID=75DBCE17448CC18BB73B808303FC01A8&currentViewMedia=2&visMode=0&valuePromptAnswers=12/23/2013^12/29/2013

Comment: `?firstparam=test1&secondparam=test2`

Comment: Be some more specific !

Comment: What does "parameters" mean? Are you asking how to concatenate more than one string? Are you asking how URLs work? What a querystring is?

Comment: Do you want to pass multiple parameters in a GET request? I think the answers in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724526/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-in-a-querystring) might help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you talking about query strings ie trying to get to a url with multiple parameters?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

cause it might look like something like this

"http://www.website.com?field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3"

if you are using a language to make this it just a matter of manipulating string variables.

Comment: http://gmail/MicroStrategy/servlet/mstrWeb?Server=gm0&Project=gmail+Production+Enterprise&Port=0&evt=2048001&src=mstrWeb.2048001&documentID=75DBCE17448CC18BB73B808303FC01A8&currentViewMedia=2&visMode=0&valuePromptAnswers=12/23/2013

I would also like to pass another value in the value prompts such as the output should look like http://gmail/MicroStrategy/servlet/mstrWeb?Server=gm0&Project=gmail+Production+Enterprise&Port=0&evt=2048001&src=mstrWeb.2048001&documentID=75DBCE17448CC18BB73B808303FC01A8&currentViewMedia=2&visMode=0&valuePromptAnswers=12/23/2013^12/29/2013

Comment: when passing values it always follows the same pattern. In this case it would be gmail/MicroStrategy/servlet/?date='12/29/2013'&user='user3101523'. it would be the controller that handles the request that determines how many parameters it can handle.

Comment: Hi,

I am new to JSP, but what I am trying to say is I want to pass &valuePromptAnswers=12/23/2013^12/29/2013 in the same and not date='12/29/2013'&user='user3101523'

Comment: Ah sorry hard to understand if i am reading this correctly you want to pass multiple answers in one parameter in the url. I think maybe the best way to do that is to maybe serialize it in a JSON object. that way it becomes one large string and can allow it be Deserialized on the controller end. A serialized json object is just one large string and therefore would do the trick of allowing you to  mass multiple items as one parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be something like ("http://www.av.com?param4="+param4+"&param5="+param5) ??

This is assuming you are already sanitizing the param values.

**Edit 1:
This is in response to your comments on the other answer.**

It doesn't really matter whether you pass `....?oldDate='12/23/2013'&newDate='12/29/2013'` or you just want to send both the dates in one single variable. Unless you can't send '^' in the URL, you can always send your data as `...?myDates='12/23/2013^12/29/2013'`.

All you would need to do in the second case is to retrieve the value from myDates, and split it around '^'. If '^' is not allowed in the URL, you will have to look for a suitable alternate. I would suggest '_'. Then again, it doesn't really matter how you pass it.