# How to pass multiple parameters through a url JS

Tags: php, html

I have this code:

```
<p><a href="./page.html?msubject=<?php echo $_GET['msubject']?>&subject=thingy">Page</a></p>
```

According to [this previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801953/how-to-pass-multiple-arguments-while-creating-url-link-using-javascript),  it should be right,

yet I get errors of a

> malformed URI reference and subject being an unknown entity.

Comment: [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: Closing PHP tag is missing

Comment: maybe you forgot the "?" at end <?php echo $_GET['msubject']**?**>

Comment: @manian When editing for formatting, I accidentally deleted it. It's not the problem. What else could be the problem?

Comment: @Andreas Would the corrected code be: `<a href=urlencode("./page.html?msubject=<?php echo $_GET['msubject']?>&subject=thingy")>`

Comment: No. There is an example on the page ;)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close your `PHP` tag correctly.

```
<?php echo $_GET['msubject']>
```

change to this

```
<a href="<?= urlencode('./page.html?msubject=' . $_GET['msubject'] . '&subject=thingy') ?>">Page</a>
```

Comment: When editing for formatting, I accidentally deleted it. It's not the problem. What else could be the problem?

Comment: Ok then try what other guys suggest, use `urlencode`, I will edit my answer. @p26528

Answer (score 0):

check if the msubject doesn't have spaces.
I'm not a php programmer but I know I have to urlencode my string before loading them in an URL

Comment: How would you urlencode before putting it into the URL? Can it not be done in 1 go? The example on php.net shows it being used on the php part, which would make it so the php would not run.

Comment: like I said I'm not a php developer but I hope this helps
http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<p><a href="./page.html?msubject=<?php echo $_GET['msubject'];?>&subject=thingy">Page</a></p>
```

You miss `**<?php ?>**`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code,

```
<?php $query = array('msubject' => $_GET['msubject'],'subject' => 'thingy'); ?>
<a href="./page.html?<?php echo http_build_query($query, null, '&amp;', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986); ?>">Page</a>
```

Please refer the below url for 'http_build_query' function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php