# Moving information from one form to another

Tags: c#, asp.net

[How the form looks like currently, I want when its ran and answers are inputted, it goes to a new page titled summary, maybe.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgY4n.png)I've been trying to move information from one form to another in C# basically web form without creating a database. I want information filled on one form like maybe a simple registration form and then answers displayed on another form.

Comment: Do you want to transfer it only when the new form is shown or afterwards aswell?

Comment: I just want it shown on a new form not afterwords, you know when the user probably fills the information, and submits it automatically goes to the next form showing the answers. @IanH.

Comment: please show some code, some example... what you try, where you stop ?

Comment: @Aristos I just added a picture.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the Informantion to be passed to a new form once, you may probably want this:

```
private string Name;
private string Password;
private string other;
public Form2 ( string _Name, string _Password, string _other ) 
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Name = _Name;
    Password = _Password;
    other = _other;
}
```

And to call the new Form you would need this:

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2 ( NameTextbox.Text, PasswordTextbox.Text, otherTextbox.Text );
frm2.ShowDialog();
```

So the information and data you want to transfer would be in the parameters of `public Form2 ( paramters )`

Comment: what if I have a drop down list and a checkbox like I have shown in the picture. there has to be a code for every tool used so it can be implemented.

Comment: please see attached image @IanH

Comment: @MaryJaneO for a listbox store the "selectedIndex" in an integer and for the check box the "checked" property as a boolean

Answer (score 0):

from your attached image, I'm assuming that you are making some web application or website, and as per your requirement I would suggest you to use `query string`

follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724526/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-in-a-querystring)

for checkboxes you can use `Booleans` and for dropdown list's selection you can simply use `strings`