# How to pass multiple parameters using Querystring in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["id"]))
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
        if (custTotle == 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect(prevPage);
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Product.aspx?id=" + id + "Customize=" + custTotle);
        }
    }

}
```

In this I want to pass two different values to the page but it is not redirecting and I get the error

"**Input string was not in a correct format.**"

at `id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);`

Any suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass multiple parameters in a querystring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724526/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-in-a-querystring)

Answer (score 2):

You have to separate query string key by & character

```
Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Product.aspx?id=" + id + "&Customize=" + custTotle);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your missing a "&" in the url:

```
Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Product.aspx?id=" + id + "&Customize=" + custTotle);
```