# Return dynamic entity in OData

Tags: c#, odata

I'm new in `OData`. I created simple `OData` project. I have controller. It returns products from DB. To increase performance I'm loading only properties (`using System.Linq.Dynamic`) when client request contains **select** row. Here is my controller:

```
  MainContext Context = null;

    public IHttpActionResult Get(ODataQueryOptions<Product> queryOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (Context == null)
            Context = MainContext.CreateInstance();
        var entities = Context.GetEntities<Product>();
        if (queryOptions.RawValues?.Select != null)
        {
            var selectedProperties = GetSelectedPropertiesFromSelectRaw(queryOptions.RawValues.Select, typeof(Product));
            if (selectedProperties.Any())
            {
                var splittedProperties = string.Join(",", selectedProperties);
                var onlyProperties = entities.Select($"new({splittedProperties})");
                var dynamicInstances = GetInstancesDynamicly(onlyProperties, onlyProperties.ElementType, cancellationToken);
                return Ok(dynamicInstances);
            }
        }
        var entityInstances = CreateInstances(entities, cancellationToken);
        return Ok(entityInstances);
    }

    List<string> GetSelectedPropertiesFromSelectRaw(string selectRaw, Type entityType)
    {
        var properties = selectRaw.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim())
              .Where(s => s != "" && entityType.GetProperties().Any(p => p.Name == s));

        return properties.ToList();
    }

    private List<Product> CreateInstances(IQueryable<Product> entities, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var list = new List<Product>();
        foreach (Product entity in entities)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            list.Add(entity);
        }
        return list;
    }

    IList GetInstancesDynamicly<T>(IQueryable entities, T type, CancellationToken cancellationToken) where T : Type
    {
        Type genericListType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type);
        var list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(genericListType);
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            list.Add(entity);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

When I request https://localhost:44326/Products it returns products: 
[image: result]

But when I request `https://localhost:44326/Products?$select=Id,Name` it is not returning anything. I putted breakpoint before `return Ok(dynamicInstances);` `dynamicInstances` contains items:

[image: result2]

EDIT: My `OData` model registration:

```
   public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");
        config.MapODataServiceRoute(
        routeName: "ODataRoute",
        routePrefix: null,
        model: builder.GetEdmModel());
    }
```

Why it isn't loading anything ?

Comment: Can you publish your OData model registration? The second query doesn’t return all fields of Product I assume.

Comment: @KosalaW, published

Comment: what do you expect as the output of the 2nd query? OData only works for registered types. Since you are selecting only two fields I don’t think OData can use “Product” model.

Comment: @KosalaW, I'm expecting dynamic entities which I set in OK method. Is it possible ?

Comment: Try : select=Id&NameSee : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724526/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-in-a-querystring

Comment: @jdweng How can it help me? I think, problem is not in query

Comment: Look at your method : GetSelectedPropertiesFromSelectRaw.  It looks like it only will work with one property and not two (ID and Name).

Comment: @jdweng, I tested it, it works with two properties

Comment: So are you passing the string "Id,Name" including the comma?

Comment: @jdweng Here is my request https://localhost:44326/Products?$select=Id,Name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198129/discussion-between-dilshod-k-and-jdweng).